# Joda Time .isAfter() producing incorrect result

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I am getting some strange results from Joda Time and I am not sure what is causing it.

I am comparing two datetimes (alarm end and stop time) to ensure the user doesn't set an alarm to end before it starts.

I used the is .isAfter() but it seem to be giving me an incorrect result.

This is the if statement:

```
if (MainActivity.alarmStartDateTime.isAfter(MainActivity.alarmEndDateTime)) {
                nextReminderTextView1.setText("WARNING THE ALARM END DATE & TIME IS BEFORE THE ALARM DATE & TIME");
                alarmSetToEndBeforeItStarts = true;

            }
```

This was the start and end datetimes:

```
MainActivity.alarmStartDateTime = 2016-11-21T00:26:45.183+10:00
MainActivity.alarmEndDateTime = 2016-11-21T00:30:00.000+10:00
```

And this was the result:

```
alarmSetToEndBeforeItStarts = true
```

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: I also just experienced this issue as well - and one thing that may be hidden is where the TimeZone is set for these instances of DateTime upon their creation. Even when parsing with a DateTimeFormatter, you aren't guaranteed to have the same time zone, it may be worth checking that out if you get a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your problem:

```
DateTime alarmStart = DateTime.parse("2016-11-21T00:26:45.183+10:00");
DateTime alarmEnd = DateTime.parse("2016-11-21T00:30:00.000+10:00");
System.out.println(alarmStart.isAfter(alarmEnd));
```

Has the following output:

```
false
```

You need to post the minimum test to replicate the issue if you think there is a bug in `isAfter()`. This is *extremely* unlikely as Joda is a pedigree library with a high degree of test coverage used in many projects around the world.

I would suggest instead the following: perhaps `alarmSetToEndBeforeItStarts` is a class field and has been set by a previous call to your quoted `if` statement. This can happen easily if you are not careful with lifecycles in Android.